# sed to comment out css file with certain font-family

Tags: css, fonts, sed, multiline

I have been searching for a way to comment out a `.css` file that may have a certain font-family indicated in the `@font-face`, `#id`, selector and/or `.class`.  I can do this with `sed` if everything is on one line with `/foobar/ a\`(append) and `/foobar/ i\`(insert) but what is the best method to do this if everything is on multiple lines?

### **EXAMPLE:**

**Before**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "foobar";
    src: url(fonts/foobar.ttf);
}

h1 {
       font-family: "foobar";
}

.foobar {
    font-family: "foobar";
}
```

**End result:**

```
/* @font-face {
    font-family: "foobar";
    src: url(fonts/foobar.ttf);
} */

/* h1 {
       font-family: "foobar";
} */

/* .foobar {
    font-family: "foobar";
} */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/{/!b;:a;$!N;/}/!ba;/font-family:\s*"foobar";/s/.*/\/* & *\//' file
```

Comment: +1, the idea is smart. Recommend to change the replace command by `s!.*!/* & */!'`, when the replace chars with `/`

Answer (score 1):

Can do it with perl and awk

```
perl -00 -lpe '$_ = "/* $_ */" if /font-family:\s+.foobar/' file
awk -v RS= '/font-family:[[:blank:]]+.foobar/ {$0 =  "/* " $0 " */"} 1' file
```

Both of these work the same way: read the file paragraph-by-paragraph (blank line delimited), test the regular expression, and add the comment markers if found.

To edit the file inplace, you would use

```
perl -i ...(as above)...

awk ...(as above)... > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file
```